# IC identification - Analog Devices with top marking "6088 N79287 LT229

Tags: identification

I am trying to trouble shoot a device. Would anyone be able to check what is the part number for this chip ?
[image]

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the application. The more information, the better we can narrow the search. How do you know it is Analog Devices?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

LTC6088 in a 16 land DFN package.

https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6088.html#product-overview

[image]

Comment: Also I there is another chip which the top marking is slightly different but it shares the same number as " 6088 ". Do you think they are the same? That is 6088  N23809  LT910

Comment: I would suspect so @mamzighasemi , one way to verify would be to check the pin outs of the other chip for consistency with the part; power, ground and no connects should make sense, plus the stuff usually attached to op amps